# jQuery toggle triggers effect instead of handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm probably overlooking something really stupid, but I can't see what it is.
I want an extra control panel to slide out from underneath the main controls. I thought it would be best to use the toggle handler for that. When I use it, it triggers the toggle effect and hides the elements with 'categories' as their class.

The code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".categories").toggle(
        function(){
            $(".expandcontrols").animate({
                right: "15%"
            }, 500, function(){
            });
        }, function (){
            $(".expandcontrols").animate({
                right: "0%"
            }, 500, function(){
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: You should show your HTML markup also or create a fiddle demo for better understanding.

Comment: That version of jQuery's `toggle` was deprecated and removed from jQuery a few years ago ?

Comment: Someone marked it as 'duplicate', which was great, because indeed the answer was there. Thanks!